# How to get all property for a custom entity in FOSUserBundle?

Tags: doctrine, fosuserbundle, symfony

I am using FOSUserBundle
I created a User entity that extents baseuser, and I added a protected property I called $apiKey. The registration form works fine.

then, I created a userController that extends controller, and in a methoid to edit my user I have:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id);
```

my $user has the apiKey property but this is empty (of course the field in the DB is not).

any idea?

thanks

UPDATE: user entity

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         * )
         */
        protected $groups;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $apiKey;

    /*    public function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
        //$this->roles = array('ROLE_USER');  //default role for new users
        }*/

        public function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getApiKey()
        {
        return $this->apiKey;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $apiKey
         */
        public function setApiKey($apiKey)
        {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getGroups()
        {
        return $this->groups;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $groups
         */
        public function setGroups($groups)
        {
        $this->groups = $groups;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your user entity ?

Comment: @smarber message updated

Comment: instead of `$em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id);` try this `$em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneById($id);`

Comment: I tried this already, anyway is not the whole $user empty, but only the property I added. looks like I have to map it somewhere else...?

Comment: This is weird because your entity looks fine, try to map it `/**
         * @ORM\Column(name="api_key", type="string", unique=true, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $apiKey;`

Comment: Also, to override the registration form I created a RegistrationFormType and I added $builder->add('apiKey'); in buildForm method. maybe I need to do something similar to create an edit form?